# Conditionally clearing setInterval

Tags: reactjs

For some reason, the condition here ("if id === reset") is not working: is neither clearing Interval nor resetting state. If I move "const id" inside setInterval, I get "undefined", which could mean it´s because of the value of this. Unfortunately, I don´t know how to fix it.

```
class Clock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
break:5,
session:25,
timer: 1500,
isRunning:false,
}

this.handleSession = this.handleSession.bind(this);
this.handleTimer=this.handleTimer.bind(this);
   }

handleSession(event){
const id= event.target.id;
let breakvar= this.state.break;
let sessionvar= this.state.session;
let isRunning=this.state.isRunning;

if(!isRunning && id==="break-increment" && breakvar<=59){
this.setState((state) => ({
  break: this.state.break +1}))}
}

else if (!isRunning && id==="session-decrement" && sessionvar>1){
this.setState((state) => ({
  session: this.state.session -1, timer:this.state.timer - 60}))}   
}   
 handleTimer(evt){
      const id=evt.target.id;
      clearInterval(this.Interval)
      this.Interval=setInterval(() => { 
        let timer=this.state.timer;
        if(timer > 0){
          this.setState({
            timer: this.state.timer - 1
          })
        }else if(id==="reset"){
     clearInterval(this.Interval);
     this.setState((state) => ({
      session: 25, timer:1500, break:5, isRunning:false}))
        }
        else{
          clearInterval(this.Interval)}
      },1000)}

Clock(){
    let minutes = Math.floor(this.state.timer / 60);
    let seconds = this.state.timer - minutes * 60;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    return minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

render() {
    return(
            <div id="container">
                <Display break={this.state.break} displayTime={this.Clock()} session={this.state.session}/>
                <p id="break-label">Break length</p>
                <Button onClick={this.handleSession} id="break-increment"/>
                <p id="session-label">Session length</p>
                <Button onClick={this.handleSession} id="session-decrement"/>
                <Button onClick={this.handleTimer} id="start_stop"/>
                <Button onClick={this.handleTimer} id="reset"/>
            </div>
)

}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Copy/Pasted your code and it appears to work: https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/SO53367240

Comment: Now you've updated your code again, but you've left out key information, like, what does your `Button` component look like, what does `this.handleSession` do? and where is the code for `this.Clock()`? You should put your code into Repl.it so we can see all the moving parts.

Comment: I posted the entire component. I can´t replace the "ids" and such, because the guidelines are very strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` statement will never be reached, because `timer` is almost always above 0, unless the timer has ran out. So when the user presses reset, the `if( timer > 0 )` case will catch, and it will never make it to `else if(id==="reset")`

Here's your code cleaned up, also note I renamed `break` to `break1` because `break` is a reserved word in JavaScript.

```
handleSession(event){
  const id = event.target.id;
  const { break1, session, isRunning } = this.state;

  if(!isRunning && id==="break-increment" && break1<=59) {
    this.setState({
      break1: this.state.break1 +1
    })
  } else if (!isRunning && id==="session-decrement" && session > 1) {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      session: this.state.session -1, timer:this.state.timer - 60
    }))
  }   
}

handleTimer(evt) {
  const id=evt.target.id;
  clearInterval(this.Interval)

  this.Interval=setInterval(() => { 
    let timer=this.state.timer;
    if(timer > 0 && id !== 'reset'){
      this.setState({
        timer: this.state.timer - 1
      })
    } else if (id==="reset") {
      clearInterval(this.Interval);
      this.setState({
        session: 25, timer:1500, break1:5, isRunning:false
      })
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.Interval);
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

## Demo

https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/SO53367240

**Note:** without your actual `Display`, and `Button` components, I had to make substitutions to the rendering.

Comment: This didn´t work. I´ll update the question with the full context.

Comment: Do you remember where, exactly? Sorry, I wanna learn and HandleSession worked perfectly.

Comment: btw, I tried your code (copypasted it). Doesn´t seem to work.

Comment: It was a copy/paste error, your weren't missing characters. As for not working, can you describe what isn't working? Can you make your own repl.it and share?

Comment: Nevermind: it works if I don´t do "else if" in second condition (reset), and leave it as "If". What does that happen though? Also, before your code, I had to add the else to avoid the setInterval from going into negative numbers but now that´s taken care of. Do you know why? Sorry, I really want to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example with ES6 arrow function:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  handleTimer = id => {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      let timer = this.state.timer;
      if (timer > 0) {
        this.setState({
          timer: this.state.timer - 1
        });
      } 
    }, 1000);
        else if (id === "reset") {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.setState(state => ({
          session: 25,
          timer: 1500,
          break: 5,
          isRunning: false
        }));
      }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleTimer('reset')}>Reset</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleTimer('start')}>Start</button>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I've used ES6 arrow function, so it can be utilized with **this** on the button click. If you prefer to stick to your implementation, make sure you bind to this in the constructor:

```
 export default class MyComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleTimer = this.handleTimer.bind(this);
      }
```

Here's a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wq253893w5

Comment: I am updating my solution to address your case

Comment: @HernanAriel see how onClick is used. Now handleTimer does not need to introduce const id as it is passed as function argument.

Comment: @HernanAriel try replacing your handleTimer function with mine (replace entire thing), then replace onClick call on the reset button with what I posted. It also seems that you are using Button custom component (because of the capital  'B' in Button), not an HTML button element. Is this what you were going to do?

Comment: I posted the entire component. I can´t replace the "ids" and such, because the guidelines are very strict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183862/discussion-between-alex-oleksiiuk-and-hernan-ariel).